# Arduino: how to store analog signals to data chunk of wav file?

Tags: audio, arduino, wav

What I want to do:
I want to build a audio recorder with my arduino. I have a mic connected to it, as well as a SD Card adapter. On a button push I want to record something and save that on the SD Card.

Problem:
I used this wav file "template" -> [How to convert analog input readings from Arduino to .WAV from sketch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484763/how-to-convert-analog-input-readings-from-arduino-to-wav-from-sketch) to create a file and write it onto my sd card. I am using this

```
    int micIn = analogRead(A1);
    writeDataToWavFile(micIn);
```

to "feed" my wav file with data. Values are mapped from -32.. to 32.. (see method in the link).

Good is, the wav file is correctly created and not corrupted, but there is no sound and the length is 0. (but bytes are written).

I also tried to use

```
writeDataToWavFile(0);
```

'cause i thought i'd get at least a silent but longer (at least existent) sound, but it didn't work.

How am i supposed to add the actual data? just raw as voltage values? mapped? 0-centered? sampled, or are they already sampled?

Comment: I wrote the answer to the question you reference, but I think I may have left in some typos . However, in my experience you’re probably better just saving data to a CSV format file or even just the raw bytes and doing the conversion to wav off of the board. You’ll tend to end up with discontinuities if you write / edit a wav straight on the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess there might be multiple different approaches on how to "maintain" and then save the data, but I seem to have difficulties on "which" data to store. So, according to your comment: What are those raw bytes? the analog pin's analog signal (in my case between 0 - 1024)? Or do I have to convert that value? That's actually what I cannot get my head around. Thanks!

Comment: If you have single stream of data and each sample point is the same number of bytes then you can save your data as a bin file. If you have 10-bit data (0 - 1023) I’d think about mapping the values to 8-bit (0 - 255) . The raw bytes are just the value of the sensor readings you have expressed in bytes. In this case, the output of analogRead is basically the raw byte data. However when you write that data to a file you need to make a choice between an unsigned 8-bit or unsigned 16-bit int type. There is no 10-bit type integer

Comment: Thansk for you answer, I guess I understand that now. 
In your Code example you had this method "writeDataToWavFile()"

´´´
void writeDataToWavFile(int data)
{
  int16_t sampleValue = map(data, MIN_DATA_VALUE, MAX_DATA_VALUE, 0, 255);

  subChunk2Size += numChannels * bitsPerSample / 8;
´´´
Is the subChunk2Size actually calculated correctly or are the numSamples missing ? That might maybe be the reason why I have a syntactically correct wav file but no sound/length?

Comment: I used hexed.it to look inside the wave file and it seems that even though data is inside, the subChunk2Size remains 00 00 00 00.

Comment: Ah, that’s because I’ve left the SD open in append mode https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75882 so although it seeks to a position it always writes at the end. Whoops, I’ll need to edit the answer when I get a chance

Comment: Thanks, then it worked, though I am still trying to figure out how to samples at 8khz, since the writeDataToWavFile() method is pretty heavy, think i am probably  going to temp. save it :) Thanks!